# Setting scale limits with `lims` for fill

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

I am trying to (naively?) set the limits of a color scale, but what happens is that the color scale itself is overridden additionally. What am I making wrong or how can it be done?

Simple example:

```
p <- volcano %>% reshape2::melt(varnames=c("x", "y")) %>% as_tibble() %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x,y, fill=value)) + geom_tile() + 
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours=hcl.colors(15, palette = "Purple-Green"))
p
```

[image: This works as expected...]

```
p + lims(fill=c(50,200))
```

changes the whole color scale:
[image: This does not]

NB: In the real world example I want to center the color scale symmetrically around 0 with a diverging color scale and I do not want to use `scale_fill_gradient2`

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1):

The reason why `lims` doesn't work here is that it adds a whole new `scale` object to the plot which overrides the one you have already specified. If you look at the code for `lims`, it does its work through sending all its arguments individually to the generic function `ggplot2:::limits`. In your case, this invokes`ggplot2:::limits.numeric`, which creates a new scale object via `ggplot2:::make_scale`. This function ends up just calling `scale_fill_continuous`.

As for why you can use `lims` after specifying an x or y scale without overwriting the existing one, the answer is: you can't, it *does* override the existing scale, and in fact warns you that it is doing so. Suppose we specify an x axis scale with lots of breaks in your example:

```r
library(tidyverse)

p <- volcano %>% 
  reshape2::melt(varnames = c("x", "y")) %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x,y, fill = value)) + 
    geom_tile() + 
    scale_fill_gradientn(colours = hcl.colors(15, palette = "Purple-Green"), 
                         limits = c(50, 200)) +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = 0:44 * 2)

p
```

[image]

Now look what happens if we add x axis `lims` to our scale:

```r
p + lims(x = c(0, 90))
#> Scale for 'x' is already present. Adding another scale for 'x', which will
#> replace the existing scale.
```

[image]

We lost all our breaks, and got a warning that our x scale was being overwritten.

So the bottom line is that passing numbers to `lims` just adds a vanilla contnuous scale to whichever aesthetic you specify. Doing `+ lims(fill = c(0, 10))` gives exactly the same result as `+ scale_fill_continuous(limits = c(0, 10))`. The answer, as you have found yourself, is to specify the `limits` argument directly in the scale you wish to add.

<sup>Created on 2022-08-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Ok, now I found the solution myself....

Did not know that there is a `limits` keyword directly:

```
volcano %>% reshape2::melt(varnames=c("x", "y")) %>% as_tibble() %>% 
+   ggplot(aes(x,y, fill=value)) + geom_tile() + 
+   scale_fill_gradientn(colours=hcl.colors(15, palette = "Purple-Green"), limits=c(50,200))
```

Still don't fully get, why `lims` overrides the whole scale. And this mean one cannot change the limits afterwards (as one can do x and y scales?

[image]